# Connect through proxy in flash

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an application made by AS3 (.swf) and this application will connect to a specific website and retrieve data and display something. It works well on PC.

And after that I need it to run on something like set-top box. The application works fine when the set-top box thing directly connect to the internet. But it doesnt work when connecting through proxy. The set-top box can still connect to the internet even through proxy. I cant set security stuff for flash because this set-top box thing doesnt have browser.

This is how AS3 connect the internet:

```
var timeloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.google.com");
timeloader.load(request);
timeloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataComplete);
```

Anyone has idea?

Comment: *Advice:* you should compile the Flash/Flex file to Adobe AIR, instead of SWF if you tend to run out of browser.

Comment: Please listen to SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, and lets see what it says...

Comment: I use Adobe Flash CS3, I publish it with setting Adobe AIR 1.0, still cant get it work.

And I tried to get the security error, it said:
[SecurityErrorEvevnt type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048"]

Comment: I got the HTTPStatus too, it said: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=0 responseURL=null]